# Xcode what is the key to tab into the next auto suggested parameter block?

Tags: xcode, key

Xcode what is the key to tab into the next auto suggested parameter block?

e.g. when typing a method the params are suggested automatically you press TAB to accept
but how to you move to the next param ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about the likes of an 'if' statement, then the key combination is control and slash

control + /

That will jump to the next pre-defined parameter for the method

Comment: Can't remember, might have been in a book. Probably Beginning iPhone 3 development.